# Etymology of Agamemnon and Priam

Tags: etymology, names

What is the etymology of the names of the kings from the Iliad?

Besides these two, I would be also interested in the etymology of the names of the other heroes from the book, such as Hector and Paris.

Am I correct that Hector shares etymology with the word "sector", that is the one who cuts/strikes?

Answer (score 7):

The currently favoured theory (e.g. in Beekes, with references) is that *Ἀγαμέμνων, variants –μέσμων and –μέμμων, is from * Ἀγα-μέδ-μων, from μέδομαι “to be concerned with”, and not from μένω (which would not really account for the second μ). Of course, in etymology everything is a hypothesis.

Comment: Why not from μέμονα?

Comment: You're right, I'd forgotten about this theory; it does account for the variants, which you can't get from *me-mn-*. But then how does -δμ- become -μν-? Are there parallels for this?

Comment: Beekes writes: “The development -dm- > -nm- > -mn- is known in various Greek dialects (other examples in Lejeune 1972: 771, where also on the development to -sm-).”

Answer (score 3):

**Agamemnon** - Greek Ἀγαμέμνων "very steadfast".

**Priam** is from the Luwian compound *Priya-muwa-*, which means "exceptionally courageous".

In Greek, ***Héktōr*** is a derivative of the verb *ékhein*, archaic form *hékhein*, "to have" or "to hold". *Héktōr*, or *Éktōr* as found in Aeolic poetry, is also an epithet of Zeus in his capacity as "he who holds [everything together]". Hector's name could thus be taken to mean "holding fast".

**Paris** is considered to be derived from Phrygian and means "wrestler".

Comment: "holding fast"? Sorry my English skill is not enough to parse this, can you explain? Also why it could not derive from the sek- PIE root?

Comment: @Anixx - "Fast" here means "firmly", not "quickly". And I doubt that the PIE root _sek-_ is attested in Greek.

Comment: The first part of Aga-memnon, btw, is the zero grade of *mega*: *mga* with syllabic *m* > *aga*.

Comment: @TKR does not the second part mean "known" or "remembered"?

Comment: There are two PIE roots *men-*, both with reflexes in Greek: one means "think, have in one's mind" (μέμονα "be eager, strive"), the other "stay, stand fast" (μένω). The names of Agamemnon and Menelaus are usually derived from the latter, the idea being that war leaders are more likely to be named "He who stands firm on the battlefield" or the like than "He who strives / has something in mind". Of course, since the roots are homonymous, there's no formal way to tell. And for Agamemnon, a meaning like "He who strives for great things" doesn't actually seem too farfetched.

Comment: @TKR is the root "stand fast" attested with reduplication? To me the first root seems totally convincing especially given that it has been already often reduplicated in PIE (memory, moment etc). Can you add this version also to the answer?

Comment: Also name "the one who wants a lot" is very much in line with the poem given that he was accused in being greedy.

Comment: Well, there is μίμνω, though that's a different kind of reduplication. But *moment* isn't from this root (it's from Lat. *moveo*); and the reduplication in *memor* isn't relevant because this adjective is originally a perfect participle (*me-mn-us-*, thus LIV), so it naturally has perfect reduplication. (I can't edit the answer -- the author would have to do that...)

Comment: There is no attested word in Phrygian that would suggest that "Paris" means wrestler. The word is not even mentioned in any list of known Phrygian words. "Considered" you say, but it is most probably "hypothesized" and not widely accepted.

Comment: @Anixx, could the perfect of "stand fast [firm]" mean "not standing fast anymore", thus implying "fallen"? This would also be in line with the poem. Keep in mind that poetry thrives from ambiguity. If the name is attested elsewhere, that does not mean that it was not poetic!

Comment: @Yellow-Sky great, now do "Achilles' son Neoptolemus (also known as **Pyrrhus**)", please. As for *Hector* (\*segh-), how does that compare to \*Herk'- "to hold" --- you know exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

In Craytilus Socrates explains the etymology as:

> *Socrates*
>   Yes, for Agamemnon (admirable for remaining) is one who would resolve to toil to the end and to endure, putting the finish upon his resolution by virtue. And a proof of this is his long retention of the host at Troy and his endurance. So the name Agamemnon denotes that this man is admirable for remaining.

Comment: While various parts of Plato's philosophy have stood up well over the millennia, his linguistic ideas…haven't. I'd only cite Plato about linguistics the same way I'd cite Aristotle about physics: to show the older theories that have now been long superseded.